# secondaries not replicating data from primary due to some HMAC issue

Tags: mongodb

Has anyone faced this issue ? Unable to re-sync replication either deleting the data directory & starting or doing rsync. Is this a bug ? What component in mongodb this "monitoring-keys-for-HMAC" refers to.
mongodb version 5.0.5

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-07T01:58:38.042+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"InitialSyncActive: Cannot refresh keys collection cache during initial sync","nextWakeupMillis":5200}}



rs.status().initialSyncStatus
{
  failedInitialSyncAttempts: 0,
  maxFailedInitialSyncAttempts: 10,
  initialSyncStart: ISODate("2022-09-06T06:49:37.037Z"),
  totalInitialSyncElapsedMillis: 119760548,
  initialSyncAttempts: [],
  approxTotalDataSize: Long("1766763843717"),
  approxTotalBytesCopied: Long("1566479075701"),
  remainingInitialSyncEstimatedMillis: 15312182,
  appliedOps: 0,
  initialSyncOplogStart: Timestamp({ t: 1662446970, i: 1 }),
  totalTimeUnreachableMillis: Long("0"),
```

Comment: That's just an information message. Do you have any other errors? What is the output of `rs.status().initialSyncStatus`? Check for `"c":"INITSYNC"`

Comment: `failedInitialSyncAttempts: 0` looks like it hasn't failed even single time but I'm curios to know `"error":"InitialSyncActive: Cannot refresh keys collection cache during initial sync"`

Comment: `remainingInitialSyncEstimatedMillis: 15312182` means 4.2 hours. Perhaps you just have to wait some more time. 1766763843717 is around 1.7 TB, give MongoDB some time to synchronize. Note, you can also copy data from existing primary, see [Copy Database Files and Restart mongod Instance](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/tutorial/restore-replica-set-from-backup/#std-label-restore-rs-copy-db-files), however it requires to stop the primary (or at least a `db.fsyncLock()`) in order to get a clean copy.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if TLS/SSL certificates are being used while establishing the connectivity to the MongoDB, then such error occurs, since keys (public/private) validation will be done during the instance startup.